# Google App Engine - Difference between local Dev server and deployed server

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I'm writing an app on the Google App Engine, and I have been able to write code that runs locally and puts data into the local datastore.  However, when I deploy the code to the google server, no data is put into the datastore.  My primary indicators that nothing is getting put into the datastore are, one, when I go to the Developer Console, I'm told there are no entries, and two, when I run the page that gets data, nothing is returned.

Do I need to define new Kinds in the app.yaml or developer console before they will work on the production datastore?

Here is my put and get methods from the data store.  Again, works in the testing environment and does not work in production, everything compiles just fine.

```
package tweetdata

import (
    "net/url"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/log"

    "github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda"
)

const linkTweetKind string = "LinkTweet"
const tweetKey string = "Tweets"
const tweetKeyID string = "default_tweetstore"

//LinkTweet contains the address extracted from a tweet and the original tweet
type LinkTweet struct {
    Address *url.URL
    Tweet   anaconda.Tweet
}

//StoreTweet is a struct used for storing a tweet in the datastore
type StoreTweet struct {
    Address     string
    Text        string
    TweetID     int64
    CreatedTime time.Time
    Retweets    int
    Favorites   int
}

//TweetScore is a struct that shows the relative score of an address based on
// it's populatrity
type TweetScore struct {
    Address    *url.URL
    score      int
    lastActive time.Time
}

//WriteLinkTweet writes a given Tweet to the datastore
func WriteLinkTweet(tweet LinkTweet, c context.Context) error {
    log.Infof(c, "Putting Tweet into datastore: %v", tweet.Tweet.Id)
    key := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, linkTweetKind, getTweetKey(c))
    created, _ := tweet.Tweet.CreatedAtTime()
    store := &StoreTweet{Address: tweet.Address.String(),
        Text:        tweet.Tweet.Text,
        TweetID:     tweet.Tweet.Id,
        CreatedTime: created,
        Retweets:    tweet.Tweet.RetweetCount,
        Favorites:   tweet.Tweet.FavoriteCount,
    }

    err := datastore.RunInTransaction(c, func(c context.Context) error {
        _, err := datastore.Put(c, key, store)
        log.Errorf(c, "Failed to write LinkTweet to datastore. %v", err.Error())
        return err
    }, nil)
    return err
}

//GetAllNewTweets queries the datastore and gets all tweets created since the last
// time given
func GetAllNewTweets(since time.Time, c context.Context) []StoreTweet {
    q := datastore.NewQuery(linkTweetKind).Ancestor(getTweetKey(c)).Filter("CreatedTime >=", since)
    out := make([]StoreTweet, 0, 15)
    q.GetAll(c, &out)
    return out
}

// guestbookKey returns the key used for all guestbook entries.
func getTweetKey(c context.Context) *datastore.Key {
    // The string "default_guestbook" here could be varied to have multiple guestbooks.
    return datastore.NewKey(c, tweetKey, tweetKeyID, 0, nil)
}
```

Comment: Post the bits of code that you're using to (attempt to) write entities to the datastore. Also, what are you seeing (or not seeing) that leads you to believe that nothing is getting saved?

Comment: Any logging on a non-nil `err`?

Comment: I'm still new to GAE, and not really sure where to see output from log.Printf (or is there an equivalent from the appengine package?

Comment: For your logging, you'll need to use the logging functions - Debugf, Infof, Errorf, Warningf, Criticalf - from a valid request context (docs found in [appengine.Context](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference#Context)) to log in App Engine. In your dev server, you'll see these logs in your terminal output. In production App Engine, these logs are stored in your Google Cloud Console for your project under Monitoring > Logs.

Comment: Post getTweetKey or just set the parent to nil and re-try.

Comment: @sridhar updated code is posted.

Comment: Since Google App Engine doesn't make the standard http.Transport available, it's necessary to tell Anaconda to use a different client context. I assume you're doing this or else it probably won't work on the dev server either.

Comment: @Sridhar, the code to download tweets is in other code, but I am using alternate transport.

Comment: Did some more work on this last night and it appears that the error was elsewhere in my code and I wasn't getting to the datastore code because I misunderstood how GAE handles Go routines.  I'm upvoting all comments in thanks for the help, but can't rightfully accept any of the answers.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the (often initially confusing) effect of "eventual consistency". Entities that are written outside of a transaction take a while to be visible to queries.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/ explains the problem. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/transactions is specific to go.

Comment: So, add transactions or wait for it and it will be there eventually?

Comment: @MrWizard54 - How long are you waiting to see the data?  Even with eventual consistency, the data is usually visible by queries within one second.

Comment: Usually, but the latency tail can sometimes get long.

Comment: At this point I'm exceeding two hours since I ran a Put(), but still do not see any data.

Comment: Do you see anything using the admin console Datastore Viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `datastore:,noindex` on any fields in the `StoreTweet` struct? In order to run any query against any fields, the datastore must first index the fields you'll be querying. So not indexing those fields will cause the query to return nil without any errors. Does your dev server automatically create an index.yaml file in your project after running your queries for the first time? The production datastore uses this file to decide which fields should be indexed, all fields not indexed won't be able to be queried. From the information you've provided, this is all I can think of that would be causing your queries to return empty.

In order to debug this further, I would browse your production datastore and make sure your data is structured properly and the values are set to what you are expecting them to be.

Comment: The Dev Server is creating the index.yaml

- kind: LinkTweet
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: CreatedTime